# Useful Qt Plugins

Tags: qt, plugins

I'm a tad new to qt and so far I really only added qwt; but I was wondering, what are some other useful qt plugins? And is there a list somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean extra gui widgets based on qt? Extra non gui Libraries based on QtCore ? Or http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/plugins-howto.html?

Comment: Yes, I mean extra libraries not supplied with the LGPL download. (So not like the multimedia library). Qwt being an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try http://www.libqxt.org/ and http://medieninf.de/qmapcontrol/

Answer (score 2):

For me, one of the useful Qt plugin was [wwWidgets](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/). Also, as I needed zip/unzip functions in one of my projects, [QuaZIP - Qt/C++ wrapper for ZIP/UNZIP package](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) helped me a lot!

---

Don't use it before, but [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) is one of the things I want to test.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[The Common Toolkit](http://www.commontk.org) ( CTK ).
[Here](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Documentation/ImageGallery) is an image gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [inqlude](https://inqlude.org/). It lists a pretty decent number of available 3rd party Qt components and add-ons.

Besides these, there are also some commercial components available, like the ones from [Developer Machines](https://www.devmachines.com/) (Ribbon, DataGrid, etc.) and [KDAB](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/) (Soap, Report, Chart).